# Add first names in first appearance

Tags: bibtex, natbib, apa-style

I want to cite in a way that in the first appearance in the text there is 
`Firstname Lastname (year)` 
of all authors and in later appearances only the last name, like for instance in the [Journal of Feminist Economics](http://www.feministeconomics.org/pages/author-instructions/style-guidelines/) . I did not find a style file that does this. At the moment I am using the style file for the [Journal of Political Economy](http://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/biblio/bibtex/contrib/economic/jpe.bst).

So my question is: Is there an existing style file, that cites also the frst names? Or where in my style file can I change this?

Comment: If switching to `biblatex` would be an option for you, this would would be possible to do.